# Online email tracing tool

Tags: email, tracing

About 2 years ago I came across an online tool that would allow you to append something to the end of a destination email address. When the email was opened, the tool would email you their geographical location. Does anyone know anything about this tool? If it still exists?

Comment: Only way I can imagine that anything like this could have ever existed would be by sending an HTML email with a tracker image and geolocating by IP address. Most mail clients block remote HTML resources now for privacy reasons so that scheme would be dead in the water.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I received an ad from such an application, but I've not researched it further.

http://www.didtheyreadit.com/

Hope that it helps